# Using Nginx to serve only Wordpress API through Blog domain

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I would like to integrate my WP blog into a non-WP site using the WP API.

My blog currently sits at `site.com/blog` so the API is hosted at `site.com/blog/wp-json`

My non-WP site at `site.com`

When a user visits `site.com/blog` or `site.com/blog/<slug>` I would like to serve non-WP site, but if i visits to `site.com/blog/wp-json/*` or `site.com/blog/wp-admin` (basically anything with `/blog/wp-*`) to be served by Wordpress.

I'm using Nginx and have this setup in `sites-available`

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)/[0-9]+.html$ /vinyl/$1-$2/ permanent;

    #add_header Cache-Control 'no-store';
}

location ~ /blog/.*\.php$ {
    root /var/www/websitename;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    set $php_root /var/www/websitename/blog;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;

}


location /blog {
    root /var/www/websitename;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    set $php_root /var/www/websitename/blog;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ ^/blog/wp-.*$ {
 #go to wordpress
}

location ~ ^/blog {

 #go to non-wordpress
}
```

In this order, anything that begins with /blog/wp-ANYTHING will go to wordpress. And if it's not taken by this location bracket, if it begins with /blog, it will go to non-wordpress